# HingeJoint2D for Person and Dog to make leash

Tags: unity3d

с помощью **HingeJoints** хочу создать обычную веревку которая не будет тянуть обьекты например
с Layer:NoJoint
Пока к GameObject Player добавил gameobject Rope и это начало веревки
дальше все прикрепляются друг к другу и последний будет dog
только у меня щас проблема такая что дог прилетает к person  и персон тоже изза этого отталкивается вообщем предложите что сделать можно пожалуйста!

````
using UnityEngine;

namespace NifuDev
{
    public class Rope : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Rigidbody2D hook;
        public HingeJoint2D collar;
        public GameObject linkPrefab;
        public int links;
        public float distanceFromChainEnd = .6f;

        void Start()
        {
            GenerateRope();
        }

        private void ConnectRopeToTheEnd(Rigidbody2D endRG)
        {
            collar.connectedBody = endRG;
            collar.anchor=Vector2.zero;
            collar.connectedAnchor = new Vector2(0f, -distanceFromChainEnd);
        }

        private void GenerateRope()
        {
            Rigidbody2D previousRB = hook;

            for (int i = 0; i < links; i++)
            {
                GameObject link = Instantiate(linkPrefab, transform);
                Rigidbody2D linkRB = link.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                HingeJoint2D joint2D = link.GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();

                joint2D.connectedBody = previousRB;

                // If it's the last link, connect it to the collar
                if (i < links - 1)
                {
                    previousRB = linkRB;
                }
                else
                {
                    linkRB.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("NoJoint");
                    ConnectRopeToTheEnd(linkRB);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```
````